# Android - how to handle/open http connection to a URL which contains non ASCII chars?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to open http connection to some given URL in the following form:

```
http://example.com/xml.aspx?RssType=1&TypeName=中文
```

I wanted to open an Http connection to it, get its inputStream, and do some parsing on the inputstream (see the code snippet below). But all I get is a MalformedURLException.

Anyone has any idea what's wrong with this URL? is the parameters "?Rss...&..." that's causing the problem or the non-ASCII chars at the end that are problematic?

**Code snippet:**

```
String feed = getString(R.string.feed_url);

URL url = null;
HttpURLConnection httpConn = null;
try {
    url = new URL(feed);
    httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  
    if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {  // exception here!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to URL-encode the parameters, in particular that 中文 bit.

Use `java.net.URLEncoder.encode("中文", "UTF-8")` — to be on the safe side, for every parameter value of the query, not only of `TypeName`.